# XPS 13 (9350) wifi issue in Loki (but not in Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: wifi, release-loki

I tried to install Elementary OS Loki on my dell XPS 13 (8350) as Freya didn't support the Broadcom BCM4350 wifi card. This card works out of the box with Ubuntu 16.04, but isn't recognized by Loki. How is it possible ? Note that I tried several distrib based on Ubuntu 16.04, and none seems to recognize or make the wifi card works well, which is very strange because as I said, it works really fine with a classic Ubuntu 16.04 install. Did someone managed to get wifi work on XPS 13 (8350) with Loki (or Freya) ?

Thanks,
Arnaud

Comment: What kernels are Loki and Freya using?  That wifi needs a 4.4 kernel or newer to work

Comment: Freya is 3.1x but Loki is the same kernel as ubuntu 16.04 (4.4) so I'm surprised this doesn't work. Is there something I'm missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After several hours trying to figure this out, switching kernels, drivers, etc. I just found the solution!

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
reboot
```

This worked for me and now i have Wi-fi :).

Comment: Yes it worked for me too ! Many thanks for the magic trick !

Comment: For what it's worth, I had to disable secure boot, remove the drivers, and reinstall the drivers. Looks like the part of setup that was supposed to temporarily disable secure boot may have failed.